# Android 11 5G fetching Cell Parameters

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-11, cellinfo, 5g

I am trying Android 11 on network type 5G on new Android studio preview release. My aim is to fetch Cell Info details. However , the method getAllCellInfo() returns an empty/null list on emulator. All emulators priori to Android 11 do return a valid value. Do I need to do any additional configurations to make this work on Android 11?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: Here in Portugal my phone is in 5G but the registered cell is CellInfoLTE, anyone with the same issue?

Comment: I am also interested in a solution, any news in this issue?